# Linking GTM variable to datalayer and accessing useful data about this variable

Tags: javascript, dom-events, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am very new to Google tag manager. I managed to implement the datalayer into my website. In every place on my website where I want to track user clicks I added this kind of code into my source code:

```
onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'google_play-click'});"
```

So now every time I click the event is added into the datalayer. How do I now send the data to GTM and how do I analyse this data in GTM ?
I created a DataLayer variable called `google_play-click` in GTM. When I go to overview/recent activity, I can see it has been successfully created but I dont know if it has been correctly linked to my datalayer variable and I cannot see any data about it.

Comment: You probably wouldn't do it that way - if you use a click trigger instead it will return the clicked elements, it's classes, id and contained text in variables that are automatically populated (you need to set the appropriate checkmarks in the variables section of  GTM).

Comment: @EikePierstorff can you please explain a little bit how you do that

Comment: Go to the GTM interface, menu item "variables" and tick the checkboxes in the "Clicks" section (second row first item). Then go to trigger, click "new", select "Click" (either "All elements" or "links only if you just want to track links). From there on every click on an element (link) will fill {{Click element}}, {{Click Classes}} etc. and you can use them in your triggers and tags. You can use them also in the same click tag to track only elements with specific classes (select in the "Fire on" section the "Click classes" variable from the dropdown and enter the classname).